# onSelectionChange stopped working, but function works on a manual trigger

Tags: google-sheets

I was highlighting headers in my sheet via grabbing cell, its row, and setting background on its ('A' + row) counterpart.  This WAS working fine with onSelectionChange().

Moved cells around on the sheet and edited the references in GAS, but onSelectionChange stopped working to highlight appropriate cells.  I even tried the new code with a manual trigger do_Selection(), and it works appropriately every time I select a new cell and press the button.

However, simply moving the working code into the onSelectionChange() function, does nothing.

I've even tried it simpler.  Just seeing if I could get a note output about what cell I've selected with onSelectionChange(), and now that's not even firing.

I don't know how I bork my highlighter function.  Again, it works perfectly fine with a manual button, but with a new cell selection it isn't happening.

```
function onSelectionChange(e){
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  
  var cell = sheet.getCurrentCell();
  var cellA1 = cell.getA1Notation();

  var r_Col = cell.getColumn();
  var r_Row = cell.getRow();

  sheet.getRange('A17').setNote(cellA1);

  // do_Selection();
}

function selectCheck() { // Manual selection trigger
  do_Selection();
}

function do_Selection() { // Selection code that was onSelectionChange(e)
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var sheet_Name = sheet.getSheetName();

  var cell = sheet.getCurrentCell();
  var cellA1 = cell.getA1Notation();

  var r_Col = cell.getColumn();
  var r_Row = cell.getRow();

  var HENKEL_RED = '#EC1B22';

  var e_Omit = [1,2,3,17,18,19,23];
  var w_Omit = [1,2,3,17,18,19,23];
  var permit = true;
  
  reset_Headers();

  sheet.getRange('A17').setNote(cellA1);

  if (cellA1 === 'G19') {
    sheet.getRange('G18').setBackground(HENKEL_RED);
  } else if (cellA1 === 'H19') {
    sheet.getRange('H18').setBackground(HENKEL_RED);
  } else if (cellA1 === 'I19') {
    sheet.getRange('I18').setBackground(HENKEL_RED);
  } else if (cellA1 === 'J19') {
    sheet.getRange('J18').setBackground(HENKEL_RED);

  } else if (sheet_Name === 'East Data') {
    for (i = 0; i < e_Omit.length; i++) {
      if (r_Row === e_Omit[i]) {
        permit = false;
      }
    }

    if (1 < r_Col && r_Col < 6  && permit === true) {
      sheet.getRange('A' + r_Row).setFontColor('#FFFFFF').setBackground(HENKEL_RED);
    }

  } else if (sheet_Name === 'West Data') {
    for (i = 0; i < w_Omit.length; i++) {
      if (r_Row === w_Omit[i]) {
        permit = false;
      }
    }

    if (1 < r_Col && r_Col < 5  && permit === true) {
      sheet.getRange('A' + r_Row).setFontColor('#FFFFFF').setBackground(HENKEL_RED);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I took a closer look at e, and was able to extract it better, instead going via way of .getCurrentCell(), even though that was working at first.

```
function onSelectionChange(e){
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
  var sheet_Name = sheet.getSheetName();

  var range = e.range;

  if (range.getNumRows() === 1 &&
      range.getNumColumns() === 1 ) {
        var cell = range.getCell(1, 1);
        var cellA1 = cell.getA1Notation();        
  }
  
  // continue into do_Selection()

  var r_Col = cell.getColumn();
  var r_Row = cell.getRow();

  var HENKEL_RED = '#EC1B22'; .......
```